# CSS handling break line

Tags: html, css

sample html (text lines break with "\n"):

```
<pre>
one
two
three
four
five
six
<pre>
```

I want to display it on browser like (two line in one row space with tab "\t"):

```
one two
three four
five six
```

is there any solution to make it possible with CSS?

Comment: Unless you are ready to change <pre>....</pre> to multiple <pre>s or other HTML tags, i guess if there is any solution out there, it is goint to be pretty complex.
A cleaner approach would be to use multiple <pre> or <ul><li> if you have control over the sample HTML..

Comment: This isn't really CSS's domain, if you want to edit content and line break/tab characters it would be much easier to do in JS.

Comment: Don't think so. Unless you wrap them in separate tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to just wrap them in separate tags. If you really want to keep your code like this, you could use:

```css
pre {
  width: 100px; /* has to be increased when the font-size is bigger */
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<pre>one two three four five six <pre>
```